# Delete customers who never ordered

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query to delete all customers which never ordered,
I am getting below error,

Unknown table 'customers' in MULTI DELETE

```
DELETE customers
FROM customers as c
LEFT JOIN orders as o
ON  c.customers_id = o.customers_id
WHERE  o.customers_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Show your database structure

Comment: DELETE FROM tablename WHERE condition.

Comment: Are sure you want to hard delete data?

Comment: Untested: DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT customers_ID FROM orders);

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle is:

```
DELETE FROM
    customers
WHERE
    customers_id NOT IN (SELECT customers_id FROM orders)
```

But strongly recommended that you do not delete data from your table, instead you may add another colum to discriminate those customers as inactive or something like that... so you avoid using DELETE commands.